# Filter an RDD based on another RDD in Spark

Tags: join, apache-spark, filter, rdd

I have this RDD's that i want to filter and it look like this:

```
text  (06.07.03.216)  COPYRIGHT © skdjh 2000-2015
File    160614_54554.vf Database    53643_csc   Interface   574 zn  65
Start   Date    14/06/2016  00:00:00:000
End Date    14/06/2016  00:14:59:999
State   "S587654"

End of  field Start of  field Connection duration
```

i want filter the first 6 lines to be like this:

```
End of  field Start of  field Connection duration
```

What's the most efficient way to achieve this? I've thought of.
Option1: create a new rdd contains this lines and filter them with join
Option2: create a function that can filter this lines 
what's the best way to do this ?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example...I'm not following what you want here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of to just get rid of the first *n* lines is this:

`data.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 > n).map(_._1)`

which should get you back to an `RDD[String]` with the first `n` entries purged.

Generally though it is preferable to look for ways to avoid having to do what is essentially a `drop` on `RDD`.

Comment: i have a file that have lines that i dont need them (the first 6 lines), so i want to filter them. another way how to start reading this file from the line number 7 (sorry my english is not good enough and im beginner with spark)

Comment: thank you for your answer. may i filter this rdd using another rdd?
thank you